# remove duplicates from an array when using laravel eloquent relationship in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, lodash

So I have an array that has an object inside of it due to eloquent relationship in laravel. So the array looks something like this:

Documents:

```
[
    {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "document",
        "supplier": {
            "id": 5,
            "name": "H.B.C",
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "document",
        "supplier": {
            "id": 5,
            "name": "H.B.C",
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "document",
        "supplier": {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "Avrora",
        }
    }
]
```

Now I'm trying to use lodash to get unique suppliers so in the above example I would want to get back
H.B.C and Avrora without another H.B.C.

What I'm trying:

```
CollectionSuppliers () {
    return uniq(this.Documents.supplier.map(({ name }) => name))
},
```

but im getting an error:

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

This means whatever you're calling `map` on is undefined. You're calling it on:

```js
this.Documents.supplier
```

so that means `supplier` is not a property of `this.Documents`. Which is true! Because `this.Documents` is an *array* of objects with a `supplier`, but the array itself doesn't have a `supplier`.

What you probably meant to do was:

```js
return uniq(this.Documents.map(doc => doc.supplier.name))
```

This maps each document to just the supplier name, and then calls `uniq` on the array of supplier names.

Answer (score 1):

You are accessing the `supplier` on the `this.Documents` object, but it doesn't exist, so it produces error

```
this.Documents.supplier.map(({ name }) => name)
```

You have to map over the `this.Documents` not on the `this.Documents.supplier` as:

```
CollectionSuppliers() {
  return uniq(this.Documents.map((o) => o.supplier.name));
}
```

or

```
CollectionSuppliers() {
  return uniq(this.Documents.map(({ supplier: { name } }) => name));
}
```

**NOTE:** You don't need lodash for this, you can get unique elements using vanilla JS also:

```js
const Documents = [
  {
    id: 6,
    name: "document",
    supplier: {
      id: 5,
      name: "H.B.C",
    },
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    name: "document",
    supplier: {
      id: 5,
      name: "H.B.C",
    },
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: "document",
    supplier: {
      id: 4,
      name: "Avrora",
    },
  },
];

const result = [...new Set(Documents.map((o) => o.supplier.name))];
console.log(result);
```